# Finding multiple index of desired condition in every 10 interval of a vector from "scratch" in R?

Tags: r

I tried finding the index of the max value for every 10 interval, hence I would like to find the index in sets of 10, when the max_value is 10 ( in the first set of 10) and 91 ( in the second set of 10).

I would like to get

```
max_value_idx
[1] 4 6
```

but I couldn't get the desired output with my code

```
vect_1 =c(2,3,5,10,1,9,4,7,6,8,21,13,51,14,11,91,41,17,16,28) 
n = length(vect_1)
max_value = vect_1[1]
max_value_idx = numeric(2)

for (max_n in 1:length(max_value_idx))
{
  # for every element in vect_1
  for (i in 1:n) 
  {
    # for every 10 interval
    for (s in 1:10)
    {
      if (vect_1[s] > max_value)
      {
        max_value = vect_1[s]
        max_value_idx[max_n] = s
      }
    }
  } 
}

max_value_idx
[1] 4 0
```

could someone tell me where I went wrong?

just by using basic operators/loops without using the operator %in% or any functions in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some (minimum) simplifications + correction to your original code:

```r
for (max_n in 1:length(max_value_idx)) {
  max_value = -Inf
  for (s in 1:10) {
    i = (max_n-1) * 10 + s
    if (vect_1[i] > max_value) {
      max_value            = vect_1[i]
      max_value_idx[max_n] = s
    }
  }
}
```

```
max_value_idx
# [1] 4 6
```

Comment: could you explain this step?

i = (max_n-1) * 10 + s

Comment: may I add that if vect_1 =c(2,3,5,10,1,9,4,7,6,8,21,13,51,14,11,91,91,17,16,28), can I get max_value_idx = c(4,6,7)

Comment: Try to add the following print statement after `i = ...`  and run it again: `print(sprintf("s = %d and i = %d", s, i = (max_n-1) * 10 + s))`. I'm not sure what oyu mean by the second question.

Comment: for the second qns, if there are two 91s consecutively and I want to record both their  index hence my output ` [1] 4,6,7 ` , recoding the second 91

Comment: That would need a number of modification to work, but you could take R18's solution and change the innermost part to `function(x) which(x == max(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here I wrote in three steps what you want in a simpler way.

```
# Define the vector
  vect_1 <- c(2,3,5,10,1,9,4,7,6,8,21,13,51,14,11,91,41,17,16,28)

# Divide it into groups of 10 elements
  vect_2 <- split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/10))
  
# Position of the elements containing the maximum values
  pos <- as.vector(unlist(lapply(vect_2, function(x) which.max(x))))
```

How `vect_2` looks like:

```
$`1`
 [1]  2  3  5 10  1  9  4  7  6  8

$`2`
 [1] 21 13 51 14 11 91 41 17 16 28
```

How `pos` looks like:

```
[1] 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vect_1 =c(2,3,5,10,1,9,4,7,6,8,21,13,51,14,11,91,41,17,16,28) 
output_index = c()

for (i in seq(from=1, to=length(vect_1)-9, by=10))
{
  max_value_idx = i
  max_value = vect_1[i]
    for (s in i:(i+9))
    {
      if (vect_1[s] > max_value)
      {
       max_value = vect_1[s]
       max_value_idx <- s
      }
    }
  if(max_value_idx > 10)
    max_value_idx = max_value_idx - 10
  output_index = c(output_index,max_value_idx)
}
```

```
> output_index
[1] 4 6
```